# Argument of type "Series[Dtype]" cannot be assigned to parameter of type "DataFrame"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pylance

I have defined the following helper methods

```
def load_excel(file_path: str, sheet_name: str = ''):
    if sheet_name == '':
        df = pd.read_excel(file_path).fillna('').apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower())
    else:
        df = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name).fillna('').apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower())
        
    return df

def build_score_dict(keywords_df: pd.DataFrame, tokens: list):
    """
    Returns a tuple of two dictionories. i.e. tuple[dict, dict]
    """
    matched_keywords_by_cat_dict={}
    score_dict={}

    cnt_cols = keywords_df.shape[1]
    
    for col_idx in range(0, cnt_cols):
        keyword_list=list(keywords_df.iloc[:,col_idx])
        matched_keywords=[]
        parent_cat=0
        for j in range(0,len(tokens)):
            token = tokens[j]
            if token in keyword_list:
                parent_cat= parent_cat + 1
                matched_keywords.append(token)
                parent_cat_name = keywords_df.columns[col_idx]
                matched_keywords_by_cat_dict[parent_cat_name]=matched_keywords
                score_dict[parent_cat_name]=parent_cat
    
    return matched_keywords_by_cat_dict, score_dict
```

My call to `build_score_dict`, as shown below

```
third_level_closing=load_excel(input_dir+'third_level_keywords.xlsx',sheet_name='closing')     
_, level3_score_dict = build_score_dict(third_level_closing, tokens)
```

is giving me the following warning/error by Pylance in VSCode. What is happening here and how to fix it?

```
Argument of type "Series[Dtype]" cannot be assigned to parameter "keywords_df" of type "DataFrame" in function "build_score_dict"
  "Series[Dtype]" is incompatible with "DataFrame"Pylance (reportGeneralTypeIssues)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Workaround

If you give `axis` a value in your call to `apply` it should fix the issue:

```py
def load_excel(file_path: str, sheet_name: str = ''):
    if sheet_name == '':
        df = pd.read_excel(file_path).fillna('').apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower(), axis='index')
    else:
        df = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name).fillna('').apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower(), axis='index')
        
    return df
```

## Explication

If you add type information to the return value of the function `load_excel` you will see that the type checker considers `df` a `Series` and not a `DataFrame`:

[image]

And if we write the function code as follows we can quickly spot that the `apply` method is the origin of the problem:

```
def load_excel(file_path: str, sheet_name: str = "") -> pd.DataFrame:
    if sheet_name == "":
        df: pd.DataFrame = pd.read_excel(file_path)
    else:
        df: pd.DataFrame = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name)

    df = df.fillna("")
    df = df.apply(lambda x: x.astype(str).str.lower())

    return df
```

[image]

If we ctrl-click on VSCode (on Windows) on `apply` we can see the following:
[image]

This shows that if the only argument the `apply` method receives is `f` the type checker can't say which version of the `apply` method is the one you want. It seems the Pylance implementation goes for the first definition it finds and this is I guess why you end up with the return of `apply` assumed to be a `Series`. When you add the `axis` argument the type checker can now go for the second definition that returns a `DataFrame`.